# Error while executing "npm start" command

Tags: npm, sass, npm-start, scss-mixins

I installed npm and changed the package.json file so that it can automatically compile the .scss file into a css file when npm start is used. the changes made are as follows.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss":"onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "watch:all":"parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
  },
```

but when I run the "npm start" command it returns an error. The error is as follows.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 watch:all: `parallelshell "npm run watch:scss" "npm run lite"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 watch:all script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DJ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-16T15_52_00_182Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 start: `npm run watch:all`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DJ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-16T15_52_00_229Z-debug.log
```

please help me solve this problem,
I want to complete my project but this error is in my way.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug from parallelshell. We will have to manually edit file to fix this error

You need to go to the file:

```
node_modules/parallelshell/index.js:105
```

Then change this line:

```
cwd: process.versions.node < '8.0.0' ? process.cwd : process.cwd(),
```

To this:

```
cwd: parseInt(process.versions.node) < 8 ? process.cwd : process.cwd()
```

Then things will work well